Using ColdFusion: Image validation
Qn is Create a form with Image name text box , description text area & Image upload field. User can upload only small size jpg,png and gif files. Add validation to check uploaded file type & file size. User should not upload a image which is greater than 1 MB.
`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="imgName">Image Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="imgName" name="imgName" required><br><br>

    <label for="imgDesc">Description: </label>
    <textarea id="imgDesc" name="imgDesc" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea><br><br>

    <label for="imgUpload">Upload Image: </label>
    <input type="file" id="imgUpload" name="imgUpload" required><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<cfif structKeyExists(form,"submit")>
    <cfset imageFile = form.imgUpload />
    <cfset imgName = form.imgName />
    <cfset imgDesc = form.imgDesc />
    <cfset allowedFileType = "image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" />
    <cfset maxFileSize = 1048576 />


    <cfif NOT listFindNoCase(allowedFileType, imageFile.ContentType) >
        <cfoutput>
            <p>Invalid file type, Only jpeg, png and gif files are allowed.</p>
        </cfoutput>
    <cfelse>
        <cfif imageFile.FileSize GT maxFileSize >
            <cfoutput>
                <p>File size exceeds maximum limit of 1 MB.</p>
            </cfoutput>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset uploadDir = expandPath("./uploads") />
            <cffile action="upload" destination="#uploadDir#" fileField="imgUpload" nameConflict="makeunique">
            <cfoutput>
                <p>Image uploaded successfully.</p>
                <p>#imageFile#</p>
                <p>Image name: #imgName#</p>
                <p>description: #imgDesc#</p>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfif>`

what is wrong with this code

Instead of posting code and asking what is wrong with this, it is better to explain what you are trying to do and how the code you have is not doing that.  Also always post any errors that are being generated by your code.  Please edit your question with this additional information so we can better help you.

The file upload (<cffile action="upload" ...>) must occur before ColdFusion can determine the file type, size, etc.
You'll need JavaScript to check the size before uploading to the server. An example can be found here.
